# Find the kernel of the operator $f \to xf(1-\frac{x}{2})$ from $L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Find the kernel of the operator $f \to xf(1-\frac{x}{2})$ from $L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]$

So after doing a u sub i found that the kernel is composed of functions s.t $\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}(u-1)f(u)=0$. However, I was wondering if there is some better way of describing the kernel. It is clear the functions that are $0$ on $[1/2,1]$ and anything on $[0,1/2]$ belong to the kernel, but those are not all such functions. Is there a more clear way of describing the kernel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the image of $f$ is $0$ then $xf(1-\frac  x 2)=0$ a.e. This implies $f(1-\frac x 2)=0$ a.e. As $x$ varies from $0$ to $1$ the function  $1-\frac  x  2$ varies from $\frac  12 $ to $1$. Hence the kernel consists of all $f$ such that $f=0$ on $(\frac  1  2, 1)$.